# How to join string by using readline()

Tags: readline, python-3.8, vcf-vcard

I coudn't find a solution and need help. I read a very hugh vCard text file with **readline()** on python3.
Now I have the problem, that some long text lines goes over multiple line like:

```
item1.ADR;type=HOME;type=pref:;;27-28\, Yakyu-cho 5-chome\nTokyo;Higashimat
 suyama-shi;Saitama;355-8603;Japan
```

I search the content with:

```
if re.search (r'.ADR;', elm):
    adr_list.append(elm)
```

may list looks:

```
['', '', '27-28\\, Yakyu-cho 5-chome\\nTokyo', 'Higashimat\n']
```

with line.strip():

```
 ['', '', '27-28\\, Yakyu-cho 5-chome\\nTokyo', 'Higashimat']
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
['', '', '27-28', 'Yakyu-cho 5-chome','Tokyo', 'Higashimatsuyama-shi','Saitama','355-8603','Japan']
```

I used also rstrip(), but I can't get the right solution.

Is there an easy way with readline() to detect the linebreak and concatenate the next related line/s?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate strings read from file with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788426/concatenate-strings-read-from-file-with-python)

Comment: your desired output?

Comment: @UmairMubeen, thanks for your hint, but in my case I have to use readline() not readlines().

Comment: @Hermann12: Can you make sure a complete 'data line' is just spanning over a single line without having line breaks inside?

Comment: @albert, Thanks. Good idea, I think. But I don't know how, I am new in python. The file .txt have thousend of lines. some of them (ADR) looks like my first code block example. The very most have only one line. I used line.strip(), but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you think about using an already available parser to read your vCard file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825919/vcard-parser-with-python

Comment: Solved. Don't allowed to post my solution, sorry.